# How can I add a WSYWYG editor to Django admin?

Tags: django, blogs, wysiwyg

What is the most simplest way to add a WSYISWG editors to admin panel on a django blog?

Answer (score 12):

You can use tinymce via django-tinymce:

http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/

You can either use tinymce on every single textfield or charfield in the admin, or you can just add to particular fields.

For the former, youset every CharField or TextField to use tinymce by using the [formfield_overides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) admin model settings. So in your admin.py:

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30})},
}
```

For the latter you change the widget for the field you want to use tinymce on. So in your forms.py:

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
```

and then tell the admin to use this form (in admin.py):

```
from models import Blog
from forms import BlogForm

class BlogAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogForm()
```

Comment: I found this on the net: https://github.com/pydanny/django-wysiwyg . Is it any good?

Comment: I haven't used it but I'm sure it also does the job.

Comment: do i create a forms.py because i currently do not have one?

Comment: yep, and then you have to tell the django admin to use that form when displaying your information, i've edited the answer to reflect that

Comment: and in the forms.py, don't i have to import some modules?

Comment: This is what i have got at the moment in my admin.py: 
`from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Blog

class AdminBlog(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass



admin.site.register(Blog, AdminBlog)`

So should i add PretendModel as a new class there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4604/discussion-between-adnan-and-pastylegs)

Comment: I'm getting this error now: `NameError at /
name 'ModelForm' is not defined`

Comment: This is what i have on my forms.py: 

`from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE
from django import forms

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))`

Answer (score 9):

You need to do few simple things (NicEdit WYSIWYG as example):

1) download needed editor and save it in some folder in your project, lets say in media folder;

2) in urls.py add next lines:

```
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...,
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': PROJECT_DIR + r'/media/'}),
    ...,
)
```

3) create folder 'admin' in templates folder and copy there file base.py from django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.py;

4) open file base.py and edit it that way - first 9 rows do not touch at all, but after 9th row add next code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/nicedit/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        nicEditors.allTextAreas({iconsPath : '/media/nicedit/nicEditorIcons.gif',
            buttonList : ['fontSize','fontFamily','bold','italic',
                'underline','strikeThrough','left','center','right','justify',
                'ol','ul','subscript','superscript','hr','link','unlink','forecolor',
                'image','upload','xhtml']
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's all. Now in admin panel in all textareas there will be available your WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to implement the solution given by Vitali Ponomar.

I choose [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) because it were just two javascript files (`nicEdit.js` and `nicEditorIcons.gif`) that I put in my `/media/js/` folder and doesn't require to change my field types in the model (I saw in [TinyMCE Documentation](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce) that requires to change the field to a HTMLField type and I didn't want to change anything in the database).

I put in the model:

```
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','lead','date')
    class Media:
        js = ('/media/js/nicEdit.js', '/media/js/textarea_content.js')

admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
```

The file `textarea_content.js` that I put in `/media/js/` folder also is used to initialize an specific textarea with some specific buttons is:

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
nicEditors.editors.push(
    new nicEditor({iconsPath : '/media/js/nicEditorIcons.gif',
        buttonList : ['fontSize','fontFamily','bold','italic',
            'underline','strikeThrough','left','center','right','justify',
            'ol','ul','subscript','superscript','hr','link','unlink','forecolor']
    }).panelInstance(
        document.getElementById('id_content')
    )
);
});
```

However if you are planning to use it for all textareas you can use `bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);` instead the above code.

Finally, be carefull with permissions (when I tried first time in production environment my javascript files were nor available because of permissions).